# How do I include cryptography package with my python script so other people don't have to install it separetely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, package

I have written a game in python. The whole game is in a single .py file. However, it requires the cryptography package to run. I want to send this game to others. I**s there a way to include the cryptography package along with my script so they don't have to install it separately using pip?**

EDIT:

The answer to my question was here:
[How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script